# Checking $R$ functions arguments

Tags: r

I was wondering how to get arguments for *R* functions. Is there any *R* function which can be used to get all arguments for a certain function?

As *R* function glm has the following arguments

```
glm(formula, family = gaussian, data, weights, subset,
na.action, start = NULL, etastart, mustart, offset,
control = list(...), model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit",
x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, ...)
```

How these arguments can be obtained on *R* console? Thanks

Comment: If R is only tag for your question then this question is better fit on StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like `formals()` or `args()`, e.g. `formals(glm)` gives:

```
> formals(glm)
$formula


$family
gaussian

$data


$weights


$subset


$na.action


$start
NULL

$etastart


$mustart


$offset


$control
list(...)

$model
[1] TRUE

$method
[1] "glm.fit"

$x
[1] FALSE

$y
[1] TRUE

$contrasts
    NULL
    
    $...
```